# Creating controller error in phpprobid

Tags: php, view, controller, customization

Created controller and tried to access it by url got an error like  404 Error

The page you are looking for could not be found.

Try checking the URL for errors, then hit the refresh button on your browser.

Used the fallowing procedure

```
 //created route

 'app-test-index'         => array(
        'test',
        array(
            'controller' => 'test',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ),
    ),

//controller

 namespace App\Controller;

  use Ppb\Controller\Action\AbstractAction,
 Cube\Controller\Front,
 Cube\View,
 Cube\Validate\Url as UrlValidator,
 Cube\Controller\Request,
 Ppb\Service;


class Test extends AbstractAction
{
public function Index()
{
    die('ok');
}
public function test()
{
    die('ok');
}
}
```

How to create model view controller in PHPProbid

how to customize PHPProbid

Thanks

Comment: How to create model view controller pages in phpprobid

Answer (score 0):

**How to create a controller in PHPPROBID version 7.8**

Step 1: Create a controller file in corresponding module

step 2: Edit the model Acl file in corresponding module

for example

a) Create a controller Test.php in module/App/src/App/Controller.

b) Add resources (Give permissions to user roles for the created controller) in

module/App/src/App/Model/Acl.php file

In our case you need to add the following lines

```
$test = new Permissions\Resource('Test');
$this->addResource($test);
$this->allow('Guest', 'Test');
```

It is **important** to note that the module/App/src/App/Model/Acl.php file will be replaced during phpprobid update 
so you need to create a folder named mods in root(IF already exist no need to create). 
Copy the file to mods folder with corresponding folder structure
In our example copy Acl.php to mods/module/App/src/App/Model folder.

Now you can access your controller

http://your_domain.com/index.php?module=app&controller=test&action=index

Comment: Thank you for help